# How to get specific byte value from raw in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

As title says, assuming the data type of column is **raw(16)**, is it possible to extract specific byte (for example, 5th byte) in PL\SQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`url_raw.substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_raw.htm#BABIFIJB) function

```
   utl_raw.substr( your_column,
                   5,
                   1 )
```

will return a `raw` which contains the 1 byte that was at byte position 5 of the value passed in.

Comment: That could help! Thanks!